# java tokenizer for strings

Tags: java, regex, stringtokenizer

I have a text file and want to tokenize its lines -- but only the sentences with the `#` character.

For example, given...

```
Buah... Molt bon concert!! #Postconcert #gintonic
```

...I want to print only `#Postconcert #gintonic`.

I have already tried this code with some changes...

```
public class MyTokenizer {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tokenize("Europe3.txt","allo.txt");
    }

    public static void tokenize(String sFile,String sFileOut) {
        String sLine="", sToken="";
        MyBufferedReaderWriter f = new MyBufferedReaderWriter();
        f.openRFile(sFile);
        MyBufferedReaderWriter fOut = new MyBufferedReaderWriter();
        fOut.openWFile(sFileOut);
        while ((sLine=f.readLine()) != null) {
            //StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sLine, "#");
            String[] tokens = sLine.split("\\#");
            for (String token : tokens)
            {
                fOut.writeLine(token);
                //System.out.println(token);
            }
            /*while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                sToken = st.nextToken();
                System.out.println(sToken);
            }*/
        }
        f.closeRFile();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like with `Regex`:

```
package com.stackoverflow.answers;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HashExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strInput = "Buah... Molt bon concert!! #Postconcert #gintonic";
        String strPattern = "(?:\\s|\\A)[##]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strInput);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the given example, when using the split() function the values would be stored something like this:

```
tokens[0]=Buah... Molt bon concert!! 
tokens[1]=Postconcert
tokens[2]=gintonic
```

So you just need to skip first value and append '#' (if you need that in your other) to the other string values.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specially asked for this, but I assume you try to extract all the #hashtags from your textfile.

To do this, Regex is your friend:

```
String text = "Buah... Molt bon concert!! #Postconcert #gintonic";
System.out.println(getHashTags(text));

public Collection<String> getHashTags(String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#\\w+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    Set<String> htags = new HashSet();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        htags.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return htags;
}
```

Compile a pattern like this `#\w+`, everything that starts with a `#` followed by one or more (`+`) word character (`\w`).

Then we have to escape the `\` for java with a `\\`.

And finally put this expression in a group to get access to the matched text by surrounding it with braces `(#\w+)`.

For every match, add the first matched group to the set `htags`, finally we get a set with all the hashtags in it.

```
[#gintonic, #Postconcert]
```

Comment: Yes that's what i want to do but it gives me errors with the getHasTags...
I want to read from a text file,tokenize it and then save it on another text file...i'm working with many textlines not just one so i'm using buffer reader.i don't know if that helps you someway!

Comment: well i think i did it but thanks anyway for the help!